# не срабатывает событие 'click' на body

Tags: javascript

Не могу понять, почему клик не срабатывает именно на body. если бы была ошибка, то и при клике на block тоже бы не работало...

```js
var bodyClick = document.body;
var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
bodyClick.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';

wrapper.addEventListener('click', function() {

  wrapper.style.backgroundColor =

    (wrapper.style.backgroundColor !== 'red') ?
    wrapper.style.backgroundColor = 'red' :
    wrapper.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
})


bodyClick.addEventListener('click', function() {

  bodyClick.style.backgroundColor =
    (bodyClick.style.backgroundColor !== 'yellow') ?
    bodyClick.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow' :
    bodyClick.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
})
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">Block</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скрипт правильный, а вот размер body - нет. Добавил css:

```js
var bodyClick = document.body;
var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
bodyClick.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';

wrapper.addEventListener('click', function() {

  wrapper.style.backgroundColor =

    (wrapper.style.backgroundColor !== 'red') ?
    wrapper.style.backgroundColor = 'red' :
    wrapper.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
})


bodyClick.addEventListener('click', function() {

  bodyClick.style.backgroundColor =
    (bodyClick.style.backgroundColor !== 'yellow') ?
    bodyClick.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow' :
    bodyClick.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
})
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">Block</div>
```